# Schema name not working in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, laravel

My Laravel project connects to SQL server database. I have a problem in my SQL server. I have a different schema like `Base.Auth.personType`. `Base.Auth` is the name of my schema and `personType` is name of my table.

Migration Code:

```
Schema::create("Base.Automation.personType", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->char('Title',500);
    $table->boolean('IsDelete');
});
```

But Laravel gives me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server] Database 'Base' does not exist.

Software version information:

```
Laravel Version: 5.4.36
PHP Version: 7.2.6
Database Driver & Version: 72
```

Comment: Why don'y you use `base_automation_person_type` ? Using lowercase is always better in databases.

Comment: @AakashTushar i can`t because some one create database and use it

Comment: Does 'Base' is you sql server name?

Comment: Try setting a `prefix` in your connection configuration and then remove `Base` or `Base.Authentication` entirely from `Schema::create()`.

Comment: Try [Base.Automation].personType when accessing the table.